# jqgrid draggable not working after paging

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using draggable jqgrid.But the issue is the rows are draggable only in the first page.After I change the pagination, the draggable for rows is not working.Can you please help me.
 Below is my code for making jqgrid rows draggable.

```
function GetAllCompanyProducts(productData) {
/// <summary>method to load the Proposal grid</summary>
//Load the grid
var tabelWidth = $("#tblCompanyProducts").width();

jQuery("#tblCompanyProducts").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: productData,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    loadui: "block",
    autowidth: true,
    mtype: 'get',
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 100, 200],
    viewrecords: true,
    colNames: ['ProductId', 'ProductName', 'Price'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: '30%' },
        { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: '30%' },
        { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: '30%' }
    ],
    sortname: 'ProductId',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: "Product List",
    width: tabelWidth - 10,
    pager: '#divPager',
    height: "100%",
    hoverrows: true,
    onPaging: function () {
        $("#tblCompanyProducts").trigger('reloadGrid');
    },

});    


$("#tblCompanyProducts").jqGrid('setGridParam', { gridComplete: MakeGridRowsDraggable($("#" + this.id)) });
```

}

And below is the method

```
function MakeGridRowsDraggable(grid) {
/// <summary></summary>
/// <param name="grid" type=""></param>

//$("#tblCompanyProducts").val(new Date().getTime());
var searchResultsRows = $("#tblCompanyProducts .ui-row-ltr");

searchResultsRows.draggable({ appendTo: "body" }); searchResultsRows.draggable({
    create: function (event, ui) { }
});

searchResultsRows.css("cursor", "move").draggable("option", "helper", "clone").draggable({
    revert: "true",
    appendTo: 'body',
    cursor: "move",
    snap: "true",
    cursorAt: {
        top: 10,
        left: -5
    },
    helper: function (event) {
        //get a hold of the row id
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');

        var rowData = $("#tblCompanyProducts").getRowData(rowId);
        var  id = parseInt(rowData['ProductId']) + "-" + rowData['ProductName'] + "-" + rowData['Price'];
        //set the data on this to the value to grab when you drop into input box
        $(this).data('colValue', id);
        var dialog = ($('#DragableWidget').length > 0) ? $('#DragableWidget') :
                     $('<div id="DragableWidget" class="draggedValue ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"></div>').appendTo('body');
        dialog.html(id);
        return dialog;
    }
    , start: function (event, ui) {
    }
    , stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: there is a sortable rows functionality in jqGrid by default.

Comment: Hi Frebin, Thanks for the suggestion.
But The requirement is to drag grid rows on to another div.
Is this possible by sortable function?

Comment: ofcourse you can do it with sortable plugin.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to use this..Thanks.. :)

Comment: is this what you want ? http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html take New in version 3.6 menu from left menu and choose Drag and Drop Rows

Comment: Yes very much similar. But I need the column values while dragging rows from one grid.

The example is not showing this..Please suggest..Thanks

Comment: that also possible with less effort .

Comment: are you loading data using ajax in jqgrid ?

Comment: The grid taking a json object as paramter.
like below

function GetAllCompanyProducts(productData) {
    /// <summary>method to load the Proposal grid</summary>
    //Load the grid
    var tabelWidth = $("#tblCompanyProducts").width();

    jQuery("#tblCompanyProducts").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: productData,

Comment: can you please update this code with your question ?

Comment: Update Done.Please check

Comment: please wait. i am creating a JSfiddle so it will be easy for you.

Comment: is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/9kLqqtfL/2/

Comment: check this one with paging http://jsfiddle.net/9kLqqtfL/3/

Comment: Frebin. I really Appreciate for the help and thank you very much.
Yes is very similar I needed but the row is now moved from the jqgrid.
Instead I need a clone of the row to the div.
And How I will format the dragged rows showing in the div.
Currently is very messy..You see what I mean..?

Comment: what you mean by "How I will format the dragged rows showing in the div"

Comment: row removing problem now solved http://jsfiddle.net/9kLqqtfL/4/

Comment: Means, the row which I am dragging should have a background color, some padding between columns .Font size should be bigger for some column... etc.
And when dragging the row from grid  to above the div ,the row draaged  not showing up

Comment: row removing problem now solved see my last comment

Comment: Frebin, Is there any update regarding my question?
Thanks..

Comment: Actually I want the draggable row to be formatted as a div and can be placed in another droppable div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by calling the method on loadcomplete with timeout.
below is the code

```
  loadComplete: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                MakeGridRowsDraggable($("#" + this.id));
            }, 2000);
```

It worked well for me.:)